# Loadable bundle in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am trying to load a loadable bundle. Code is given below.

```
NSString *fullPath = @"/Users/xyz/Desktop/MyPlugin.bundle"; // Assume this exists.
NSBundle *bundle;
Class principalClass;
id instance;
bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:fullPath];

// Read Principal class
principalClass = [bundle principalClass];
instance = [[principalClass alloc] init];
```

How do I get/set a property in instance class? `instance` is of type id and it doesn't know the bundle's class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use KVC to set/get properties and you can probe the object with `respondsToSelector` before calling `performSelector` on the object.

This is not ideal though, and generally you would be expected to know what the principle class is, and therefore understand what can be done with it.

Finally, what does this loadable bundle provide that a `.framework` does not?